# onTouchListener motion - action up and move

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motion

I have a button that types something in edit text and I am using on touch listener to do so when I press for audio to get played when left number gets typed.

```
zero.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                sp.play(soundIdShot1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1f);

                rect = new Rect(zero.getLeft(), zero.getTop(), zero.getRight(), zero.getBottom());

            }
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                if(!rect.contains(zero.getLeft() + (int) motionEvent.getX(), zero.getTop() + (int) motionEvent.getY())){

                }
            } if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                number.append("0");

            }
```

So, what I want to do is when I press, a sound is made and when I remove my finger the number gets typed in edit text field and when I move my finger outside the button's region with swipe nothing happens and nothing gets typed so as you get from the code I made it work with action down and action up but I can't figure it out with action move and how to make it work as I want